# Is it possible to export the Statistics from a Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Statistics are added to the new version (beta 1.5) of Minecraft. It would be fun, to have a webpage that shows these statistics, like who was the one with the most deaths or something like that.

So my question: Is there a way to export these statistics in any form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of answering my own question here, but:

It is not possible to export the statistics from a Server. This is for pretty simple reasons, as the statistics are not saved on the server. Statistics reside in the users *.mincraft/stats* folder. I refer here to the Triva section of the Achievements part in the minecraft wiki: [1](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Achievements#Trivia)

Answer (score 9):

**Short Answer:** There will be but no one has written it yet.

**Long Answer:** As 1.5 has recently released no one yet knows how the file-format for a player has changed. However I expect it to be quickly reverse engineered after it is released. Keep an eye on the [Programs and editors page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Programs_and_editors) of the minecaft wiki and the [Alpha](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Alpha_Level_Format) and [Beta](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Beta_Level_Format) file format to see how it is storing it..

Comment: Why the -1? I explained why we don't have it yet and gave resources of where it will be available when it is released.

Comment: It has been released already.

Comment: @StrixVaria, haven't logged in in the last few days and I just checked the current version on the [minecraft wiki homepage](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Minecraft_Wiki) before I posted to see if it was out yet/was the programs already there.

Comment: Also worth noting: As soon as the stats are reverse engineered, they will be able to be **faked**!

Answer (score 2):

Just adding stuff on here. If you are running a Bukkit server for MC, you can use [MCStats](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/admin-mcstats-v3-0-minecraft-player-statistics-1000.29010/) which I have used even before the official client had stats. It takes care of any user stats in-game, dan can even save it to a DB, which can then be used to create userstats webpages.